# MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mono

**Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly**

I am not unable to write to mongo cluster.
It suddenly stopped working, it was working fine.

I have attached the logs for your refernece.
Thanks

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:618)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:496)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:327)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:277)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:493)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

**What i tried?**

Though after several failure attempt to restart my applicaition, i am to able to start it.
but it finally goes back to this state.

**What i am expcting.**

I am expecting to get this issue resolved. This is really frustrating.